# Convert SimpleDateFormat year to integer

Tags: java, android

I want to convert this year

`SimpleDateFormat actualYear = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");`

in an Integer variable.

Thank u!!

Comment: Do you want to convert `actualYear` to an integer? Have you tried `Integer.parseInt(actualYear);`?

Comment: it's say "the method parseInt doesn't have any method that receive simple date format"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get `int year` from `year string`, which is in yyyy format,

```
int year = Integer.parseInt("2014");
```

If you want to get `int year` from `current year`,

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

If you want to get `int year` from `date object`,

```
String yearString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(date);
int year = Integer.parseInt(yearString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SimpleDateFormat` object just formats `Date` objects into strings.  It is not actually aware of the date till you ask for it to format a date.  The below example will print the year `2015`

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
String formattedDate = format.format(new Date());
int year = Integer.parseInt(formattedDate);
System.out.println(year);
```